# Execution order in JavaScript without async

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I've seen quite a few questions about exection order issues in JavaScript involving ajax calls.

If there are no ajax calls, is it safe to assume that code will execute from top to bottom?

Say, I have this code below. None of the functions that I'm calling have any async calls in them.

```
someFunction() {

   // Call some external function
   doSomething();

   // Then call another external function
   const x = doSomethingElse();

   if(x === 0) {

      // Call third function
      thirdFunction();
   }

}
```

Currently, I'm running into a situation where it appears as if `doSomething()` is not getting called first. Is this possible?

P.S. I'm having this issue in a React/Redux app and `doSomething()` is an action that is supposed to reset/clear something in the store but currently that's not working.

Comment: did you debug that if your cursor goes inside dosomething() or  not?

Comment: Is something else calling it? Is it getting called before the data arrives, and then again when it does?

Comment: When I step through the code, I do hit `doSomething()` first. So the order seems OK but for some reason, the code is not hitting the reducer. So, it's a different issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. If you don't have any function which has asynchronous calls like AJAX, execution order is always the same as it is.

Answer (score 1):

Along with ajax calls promises that don't resolve (for example event listeners waiting for an event that never happens) and timeout code that gets pushed to next event cycle are also async.

If doSomething() has any one of these then it might not get executed.